# Django annotate related field

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to optimize a simple django query to prefetch all the latest values.

```
sensors = Sensor.objects.all()
```

Here is the model:

```
class Sensor:
    last_record_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class Record:
    value = models.FloatField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey('hardware.Sensor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Before, Sensor model had a foreign key (last record) to record and all the records could be retrieved simply by adding:

```
.select_related('last_record')
```

To optimize the database, I removed that foreign key and replaced it with a datetime field named last_record_at.

I am using Django 2.0 and I am wondering if there is a pretty ORM way to retrieve all the sensors and last records in one (or two) query using subqueries, annotation or prefetching.

Something like (it does not work):

```
record_sub_query = Record.objects.filter(
    created=OuterRef('last_record_at'), 
    sensor_id=OuterRef('pk')
) 
sensors = Sensor.objects.all().annotate(
    last_record=Subquery(record_sub_query[:1])
)
```

or using prefetch:

```
sensors = Sensor.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'records', 
        queryset=Record.objects.filter(created=F('sensor__last_record_at'))
    )
)
```

The only alternative I see is writing Raw SQL for this rather simple problem.

Comment: show your current models and raw select do you want

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the other way around: you currently try to retrieve all `Sensors`, then get their latest associated `Record`. Why not retrieve all `Records` that have a `Sensor` such that `sensor.last_record_at == record.created` ?

This way:

```
Records.objects.filter(sensor__last_record_at=F('created')).select_related('sensor')
```

would do the job.

This assumes you never have two records at the same time for a given sensor, otherwise, you could get several times the same `Sensor`, and that every `Sensor` has a `Record` with the `last_record_at` date.

Comment: Upvote for an interesting workaround, but there are two issues with that solution - 1. It doesn't retrieve sensors which have null for last record (e.g. user wants to know which sensors aren't working yet). 2. In my case the serializers are in following order Sensor -> Record. Changing the serializers would break the app for client (mobile) devices.  So I would have to manually change the order of objects in python to return them to Sensor -> Record order.