# Using `select_related` with a table with composite primary key [Django]

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way for Django to support composite primary key in combination of `select_related` or `prefetch_related`?

I have a Records table with a composite primary key (device_id, created) with a schema like this (simplified):

```
class Records(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        unique_together = (("device", "created"),)

    # The primary key is really (device_id, created)
    device = models.ForeignKey("hardware.Device", primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

A record belongs to a Device, which is modeled like this (simplified):

```
class Device(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey("cars.Car", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_record_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I wish to run a query that will return a list of devices, but for each one also
contain the last record.

In theory, this would be something like that:

```
Device.objects.filter(...).select_related("car", "last_record")
```

But obviously "last_record" is not a foreign key, since Records contains a composite primary key which Django doesn't support.

What would be the best way to do this, other than rewriting the query in raw sql? Is there a reasonable way to override select_related to handle composite keys?

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986270/django-annotate-related-field, unfortunately, there still seems to be no solution to this problem.